# Servlet - Passing session information to the html/javascript

Tags: java, authentication, servlets

We have purchased a web application(qmatic) in which data/information is saved to the database. Those data is used by another webapplication(pentaho) to generate reports. Also we have a webapplication in which we planning to expose pages with highest importance from different webapplications to the company owners.
web applicaiton1 (WA1)- qmatic
web applicaiton2 (WA2) - pentaho
web application3 (WA3) - myapp

WA1 and WA2 are integrated with Single sign on so that we we logged into WA1 we could access WA2.
**REQUIREMENT:**  We need to access a page inside WA2 from WA3 by providing WA2 username password.

I created a servlet(myservlet) in which the required page is loaded to the servlet using passed authentication details.
localhost/WA2/myservlet?page=link&userid=admin&password=pass
The servlet could load the html source code of the page using com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.

```
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(responseText);
```

ISSUE
The html code returned from the serlvet contain links to js,css,other html (frames) of a site which required authentication

**QUESTION**
Is there a way I could pass cookieid or something from the java code to the client side (web browser) ?